# spark-shell with colored repl

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Running `spark-shell` with scala. Scala has the `-Dscala.color` argument for a colored REPL. I want the same for spark. Tried `spark-shell -Dscala.color` but this wasn't the way to get. How can I get the colored REPL for spark?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use spark.driver.extraJavaOptions to pass option to the scala REPL

```
spark-shell --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dscala.color"
```

Answer (score 5):

The following is working for me, but on Spark 2 only.

```
 ./spark-shell --driver-java-options='-Dscala.color'
```

I also tried it on Spark 1.6.0 but the colors were not activated.